# I'm facing difficulties with image uploads using the requests library in Python

Tags: python, image, upload, multipartform-data

I'm facing difficulties with image uploads using the requests library in Python. I'm trying to send an image file to a server endpoint, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.it response 200 but image not showing in the webpage.(enctype="multipart/form-data" )

```
import requests

url = "https://userconf.exblog.jp/api/image/upload/"
cookies = {

}

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Origin': 'https://userconf.exblog.jp',
    'Referer': 'https://userconf.exblog.jp/image/',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

files = {'file': open("heart-confetti-celebration-background_805687-804.jpg", 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers ,files=files , cookies=cookies)


if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Upload successful!")
    print(response.text)
else:

    try:
        error_message = response.json()["error"]["message"]
        print("Error:", error_message)
        print(response.text)
    except Exception as e:`
        print("Failed to parse error message:", str(e))
```

any way to upload this image ?

Comment: any specific error you are facing?

Comment: @Ajay {"displayAnnounce":true,"genre":[],"error":{"message":"\u753b\u50cf\u306e\u30a2\u30c3\u30d7\u30ed\u30fc\u30c9\u306b\u5931\u6557\u3057\u307e\u3057\u305f\u3002\u3057\u3070\u3089\u304f\u3057\u3066\u304b\u3089\u518d\u5ea6\u304a\u8a66\u3057\u304f\u3060\u3055\u3044\u3002"}}

Comment: The error message is in Japanese and says: "An error occurred in the image upload. Please try again after a short while." Likely some server-side error in a misconfigured endpoint (it should be returning an error code like 500, not 200).